# Loss of data after updating .Net TableAdapter

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tableadapter

I had a program working with a database I created using SQL Server Compact Edition. Everything was updating and showing fine. Then I decided to change the Fill SQL statement to order by a field. After doing that I lost most of the data, with only 2 records remaining.

The 2 records were test records I added manually in SQL Server Management studio, before starting to build the program, and I thought I had deleted them. Anybody any ideas of what has happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your sdf file set as content file in VS ?
if true, the previous run of your app had maybe worked with the bin{configuration}\yourdb.sdf file.
For any reason (clean, rebuild, ...), the sdf file in your project may has been redeployed to the bin{configuration} folder...

Comment: Yeah it was a content file and it was deployed to the bin folder, but the only files I can find are all of the really old database. So it's possible that my change has overwritten the database then? Not pleased.

Comment: @anothershrubery:  You may want to consider setting the `Copy to Output Directory` property of that sdf file to `Copy if newer`.  Then it *should* only copy when the file doesn't exist or you have made a change to one in VS.